# Finding an exponential curve

Tags: fitting

I'm working on an exercise in Stewart's Single Variable Calculus: Early Transcendentals, 8th Edition, which asks you to find an exponential curve that fits some data. I tried using the FindFit function in Mathematica as follows

```
Data = {{0, 37}, {4, 47}, {8, 63}, {12, 78}, {16, 105}, {20, 
   130}, {24, 173}}

FindFit[Data, a*b^t, {a, b}, t]

(*  {a -> 36.7826, b -> 1.06633}  *)
```

As a result, f(t)=36.7826(1.06633)^t. But I'm not sure how to arrive at the book's solution, which is f(t)=36.89301(1.06614)^t.

And how would we use the TRACE feature or the equivalent Mathematica function to determine how long it takes for the bacteria count to double?

Comment: Is there any hint how the book solution is derived?

Comment: Nope. Though the function produced by Mathematica does seem like a good fit when graphed together with the scatter plot of the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that if you fit the `Log` of your data using `Fit`, where the model is a linear function of `t`, then you get the result in the book. Concretely,

```
logData = Map[{#[[1]],Log[#[[2]]]}&, Data];
Exp[Fit[logData,{1,t},t]]
```

gives

```
E^(3.6080221696332897 + 0.06404214613230091*t)
```

which matches the result you quote since

```
Exp[3.6080221696332897`]
(* 36.8930124875266` *)

Exp[0.06404214613230091`]
(* 1.0661373313796498` *)
```

**Comment.** Fitting an $a \cdot b^t$ model is a common thing, and reducing to [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) using $\log(a\cdot b^t) = \log a + t \log b$ is a common trick, see for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html).

The result differs slightly from nonlinear least squares fit using `FindFit` since taking the log changes the error function that is minimized.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to make this code work for an $a \cdot b^{-t}$ model; that is, I'm unable to arrive at the solution given in my book. Data = {{1,76},{4,53},{8,18},{11,9.4},{15,5.2},{22,3.6}}. Book's solution is $96.39785 \cdot (0.818656)^{t}$.

Comment: The model $a \cdot b^{-t}$ and the model $a \cdot B^t$ are equivalent, by identifying $b = 1/B$. I agree with you, for your new `Data` I also do not obtain `96.39785*0.818656^t`. Looking at `Show[{ListLogPlot[Data], LogPlot[96.39785*0.818656^t, {t,1,22}]}, PlotRange->All]` one sees that the $t=22$ point comes with a big error. Perhaps the fit was made without the $t=22$ point? I therefore tried to fit `Most[Data]` and this gives something closer to `96.39785*0.818656^t` but it does not match exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Without additional information it isn't possible to verify the book solution!

For second part of your question try

```
data={{0, 37}, {4, 47}, {8, 63}, {12, 78}, {16,105}, {20, 130}, {24,173}}; 
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*b^t, {a, b}, t ]

Solve[fit[T] == 2 fit[0], T]
(*{{T -> 10.7922}}*)
```

Comment: I used Solve[f[t]==2f[0],t] to get {{t->10.7928}}. But the output says Solve: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. With your approach, I get {{InverseFunction[
     NonLinearModelFit[{{0, 37}, {4, 47}, {8, 63}, {12, 78}, {16, 
        105}, {20, 130}, {24, 173}}, a b^t, {a, b}, t], 1, 1][
    2 NonLinearModelFit[{{0, 37}, {4, 47}, {8, 63}, {12, 78}, {16, 
         105}, {20, 130}, {24, 173}}, a b^t, {a, b}, t][0]] ->.. along with the same error message

Comment: @Karam That's only a warning message. Alternatively try `NSolve[{fit[T] == 2 fit[0], 50 > T > 0}, T]`

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get the warning messages: (1) InverseFunction: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses, (2) NSolve:: The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information. Output={{}}

Comment: Restart your kernel and execute the code from my answer

Comment: Works now! Output is FittedModel[36.7826*1.06633^t] and {{T->10.7922}}. Thanks :)